# docker-compose with podman won't allow to run entrypoint

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, podman

I use Fedora 35 Silverblue.
I followed [this](https://fedoramagazine.org/use-docker-compose-with-podman-to-orchestrate-containers-on-fedora/) article on how to make podman and docker-compose friends in rootless mode.

I made a simple project:

```
.
├── docker-compose
│   └── app
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       └── entrypoint.sh
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Permissions for `docker-compose/app/entrypoint.sh` are `-rwxrwxr-x.`.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    image: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker-compose/app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    entrypoint: docker-compose/app/entrypoint.sh
```

`docker-compose/app/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

`docker-compose/app/entrypoint.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello world"
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build` I receive:

```
Removing app
Building app
Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.
STEP 1/2: FROM ruby
STEP 2/2: WORKDIR /usr/src/app
--> Using cache 39d51dee76399b2b7f06dc174e240f55b57acf4608a639146c0f67fd22b5bdb6
COMMIT app
--> 39d51dee763
Successfully tagged localhost/app:latest
Successfully tagged localhost/test-compose_app:latest
39d51dee76399b2b7f06dc174e240f55b57acf4608a639146c0f67fd22b5bdb6
Recreating 9b852c5536a3_app ... done
Attaching to app
app    | /bin/bash: /usr/src/app/docker-compose/app/entrypoint.sh: Permission denied
app exited with code 126
```

So, it can run the entrypoint though can't access the bash inside container as far as I understand.

The same project runs ok on MacOs though with docker.
If I copy the entrypoint in dockerfile it works but I don't want to rebuild my image every time I change something in entrypoint.

Is there a possibility to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance

UPD: It doesn't work even if entrypoint is copied

`docker-compose/app/Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby

COPY docker-compose/app/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

`docker-compose/app/entrypoint.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello world"

whoami

pwd

ls -la .
```

```sh
$ docker-compose up --build
Building app
Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.
STEP 1/4: FROM ruby
STEP 2/4: COPY docker-compose/app/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
--> Using cache 6da30c949d2f7c7cf1f4a293c3f4aebe23843e87a124317afafe67cdc117e6ab
--> 6da30c949d2
STEP 3/4: ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
--> Using cache 6fdcaf571d83ac713235b0bb3c816f707b4257b6f55911675ef65a91d981c41d
--> 6fdcaf571d8
STEP 4/4: WORKDIR /usr/src/app
--> Using cache 70f7f580ac7dd13fdace59fe2bc26c694105f76e9c87a33fc24b38299438b216
COMMIT app
--> 70f7f580ac7
Successfully tagged localhost/app:latest
70f7f580ac7dd13fdace59fe2bc26c694105f76e9c87a33fc24b38299438b216
Recreating app ... done
Attaching to app
app    | Hello world
app    | root
app    | /usr/src/app
app    | ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
app exited with code 2
```

Seems like user inside container lacks the permissions but user is `root`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're running on a system running SELinux. You need to [modify your bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-the-selinux-label) to modify the labelling of your file to make it accessible inside the container:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    image: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker-compose/app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app:z
    entrypoint: docker-compose/app/entrypoint.sh
```

Note the `:z` added to the bind mount.

Comment: worked like a charm. from docs we can read: you can add the z or Z options to modify the selinux label of the host file or directory. So we are effectively modifying host... how dangerous is that?

Comment: I think the only real risk is the one identified in the documentation: "Bind-mounting a system directory such as /home or /usr with the Z option renders your host machine inoperable and you may need to relabel the host machine files by hand." Otherwise, the impact in most cases will be minimal -- you are effectively marking a file or directory as "available to containers", which only matters if you're bind mounting that file/directory into a container.

Comment: It worked great and I've been using it for a long time. Though I had to switch back to docker for some reasons and what surprised me is that I didn't have to add `z` option...

Comment: The `:z` option changes the selinux labelling on the source directory. As long as you're not working with a new directory, that labelling will be persistent. That might be what's causing this behavior...